# Javascript rendering

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using Yshout and am looking to change the colour of the nickname section.

I have found the following code

```
'<div id="' + id + '" class="ys-post' + (post.admin ? ' ys-admin-post' : '') + (post.banned ? ' ys-banned-post' : '') + '">' +
            (this.prefs.timestamp> 0 ? '<span class="ys-post-timestamp">' + time(post.timestamp) + '</span> ' : '') +
            '<span class="ys-post-nickname-xbox">' + post.nickname + this.prefs.nicknameSeparator + '</span> ' +
            '<span class="ys-post-message">' + post.message + '</span> ' +
            '<span class="ys-post-info' + (this.prefs.info == 'overlay' ? ' ys-info-overlay' : ' ys-info-inline') + '">' + (post.adminInfo ? '<em>IP:</em> ' + post.adminInfo.ip + ', ' : '') + '<em>Posted:</em> ' + dateStr(post.timestamp) + ' at ' + time(post.timestamp)  + '.</span>' +
            '<span class="ys-post-actions"><a title="Show post information" class="ys-info-link" href="#">Info</a>'  + (post.adminInfo ? ' | <a title="Delete post" class="ys-delete-link" href="#">Delete</a> | ' + (post.banned ? '<a title="Unban user" class="ys-ban-link" href="#">Unban</a>' : '<a title="Ban user" class="ys-ban-link" href="#">Ban</a>') : '') + '</span>' +
        '</div>';
```

The part `<span class="ys-post-nickname-xbox">` I want to be dependant on the results of a mysql query.

I will be searching to find out if the member is either an xbox or playstation member.

The query for this is

```
$q = $database->getFormat($_SESSION['id']);
```

After using a while loop to get the answer, how can i manipulate the javascript code to use ys-post-nickname-xbox if xbox or ys-post-nickname-playstation if playstation..

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to do `ys-post-nickname xbox||playstation` so that the javascript can reference `ys-post-nickname` and not need to worry about `xbox||playstation`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that `ys-post-nickname-xbox` is a class that you made and is not a required class by YShout. In which case you could use `ys-post-nickname` as your class for YShout and then add a new class of `xbox` or `playstation` depending on which that user is.

Comment: Yeah ok, but how do I do that?

Comment: I daon't understand how to get that query involved I mentioned earlier and use the results.

Comment: How are you outputting that class at the moment?